# adding sprites to a group

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am trying to display a group of Sprite to the screen, however, my code below displays a blank screen. I've been at this for a while and i dont know why this doesnt work at the logic seems correct. the main problem occurs in the sprite method where i am trying to add the sprites at a random position. The sprites are then drawn in the gameLoop method.

Any suggestions?

```
import pygame, sys, random
pygame.init()
troll = pygame.image.load("image.png")
black = (0, 0, 0)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 640
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 400
sprite_width = 5
sprite_height = 5
spriteCount = 5


class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    pygame.init()
    sprite = pygame.sprite.Group()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

    def __init__(self, Image, pos):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image =pygame.Surface([0, 0])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = pos

    @classmethod  
    def sprite(self):
       for i in range(spriteCount):
            tmp_x = random.randrange(0, SCREEN_WIDTH)
            tmp_y = random.randrange(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
            # all you have to do is add new sprites to the sprite group
            self.sprite.add(Sprite(troll, [tmp_x, tmp_y]))

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += 1
        self.rect.y += 2
        if self.rect.y > SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.rect.y = -1 * sprite_height
        if self.rect.x > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.rect.x = -1 * sprite_width

    @classmethod
    def setImage(self,Image):
        self.image=pygame.image.load(Image)

    @classmethod       
    def gameLoop(self):
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640, 400])
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            screen.fill(black)

            # to update or blitting just call the groups update or draw
            # notice there is no for loop
            # this will automatically call the individual sprites update method

            self.actor.update()
            self.actor.draw(screen)

            pygame.display.update()
            self.clock.tick(20)

Sprite.sprite()
Sprite.setImage("image.png")
Sprite.gameLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@classmethod
def setImage(self,Image):
    self.image=pygame.image.load(Image)
```

Here, you should name the first parameter `cls`, not `self`, since it's a class method, not an instance method. Also, parameter-names should be lowercase (`image` instead of `Image`).

---

```
@classmethod       
def gameLoop(self):
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640, 400])
    while True:
        ...
```

Same here. Also, I don't know why your gameloop is part of your `Sprite` class. Also, you should not name your class `Sprite` in the first place, as it will just create confusion with pygame's `Sprite` class.

---

```
class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    ...
    sprite = pygame.sprite.Group()
    ...

    @classmethod  
    def sprite(self):
        ...
```

Here you have a field called `sprite` and a class level function `sprite`. This will not work, as the method will overwrite the field. So whenever you want to access the field `sprite`, you will access the function `sprite` instead.

---

```
@classmethod       
def gameLoop(self):
    ...
    self.actor.update()
```

`Sprite.actor` does not exit. You never created such a field.

---

```
def __init__(self, Image, pos):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image =pygame.Surface([0, 0])
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.topleft = pos
```

Here, you pass an argument called `Image`. However, you don't use it but an empty `Surface` .

---

Here's a running version of your code:

```
import pygame, sys, random

pygame.init()
troll = pygame.image.load("image.png")
black = pygame.color.Color('black')
SCREEN_WIDTH = 640
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 400
spriteCount = 5


class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    actors = pygame.sprite.Group()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

    def __init__(self, image, pos):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = pos

    @classmethod  
    def init(self):
       for i in range(spriteCount):
            tmp_x = random.randrange(0, SCREEN_WIDTH)
            tmp_y = random.randrange(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
            self.actors.add(Sprite(troll, [tmp_x, tmp_y]))

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += 1
        self.rect.y += 2
        if self.rect.y > SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.rect.y = -1 * self.rect.height
        if self.rect.x > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.rect.x = -1 * self.rect.width

    @classmethod       
    def gameLoop(self):
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            screen.fill(black)

            self.actors.update()
            self.actors.draw(screen)

            pygame.display.update()
            self.clock.tick(20)

Sprite.init()
Sprite.gameLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks for this, say if i dont want to use class methods and i instead used 


`troll = Sprite()
troll.init()
troll.gameLoop()`



The init method only class the first one, it doesnt perform method overloading, how do I get around this problem?